# React: get параметры в useEffect

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, запрос, get

Использую параметр из строки url, чтобы передать его в ajax запросе внутри useEffect. Получаю такую ошибку: `conditional could make the dependencies of useEffect Hook`

```
let query = new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
let sort = query.get('sort') ? JSON.parse(query.get('sort')) : [];
useEffect(() => {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        data: {jwt: localStorage.getItem('jwt'), sort: sort},
        ...
}, [sort]);
```

Как можно исправить? Советует useMemory, но тот хук в свою очередь агрится на query. Как я понял - проблема в параметрах строки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сейчас `sort`, при каждом рендере будет **новым** объектом, соответственно при передаче его в качестве зависимости приведет к выполнению `useEffect` на любое изменение компонента.

Сохранить значение можно с помощью `useMemo`, позволяющее получать один и тот же объект, если ничего не поменялось

```
const query = useLocation().search;
let sort = useMemo(()=> new URLSearchParams(query).get('sort') ? JSON.parse(query.get('sort')) : [], [query]);
```

Теперь значение `sort` обновиться только если изменился текущий `query`.